# Bitwise operations and shifts problems

Tags: c++, c, bit

I am testing the function fitsBits(int x, int n) on my own and I figure out there is a condition that doesn't fit in this function, what is the problem?

```
/*
* fitsBits - return 1 if x can be represented as an 
*  n-bit, two's complement integer.
*   1 <= n <= 32
*   Examples: fitsBits(5,3) = 0, fitsBits(-4,3) = 1
*   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
*   Max ops: 15
*   Rating: 2
*/
int fitsBits(int x, int n) {
   int r, c;
   c = 33 + ~n;
   r = !(((x << c)>>c)^x);
   return r;
}
```

It seems like it gives the wrong answer in

```
fitsBits(0x80000000, 0x20);
```

It gives me 1, but actually it should be 0...
How could I fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: doesn't it should be -2147483648? which is in the range

Comment: Sorry i can't see the link your post, could you post it again plz?

Comment: If `int` is a 32-bit type, then `fitsBits(x, 0x20)` should return 1 for *any* value of `x` because `x` *is* a 32-bit value. Recall that 0x20 = 32.

Comment: supplying `0x80000000` as `x` causes implementation-defined behaviour because this is greater than `INT_MAX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fitsBits(0x80000000, 0x20);`

This function returns `1`, because the first argument of your function is `int`, which is (in practice these days) a 32 bit signed integer. The largest value that signed 32 bit integer can represent is 0x7FFFFFFF, which is less than the value you are passing in. Because of that your value gets truncated and becomes `-0x80000000`, something that 32 bit integer can represent. Therefore your function returns `1` (yes, my first argument is something that can be represented using `0x20 = 32` bits).

If you want your function to properly classify number `0x80000000` as something that cannot be represented using 32 bits, you need to change the type of the first argument of your function. One options would've been using an `unsigned int`, but from your problem definition it seems like you need to properly handle negative numbers, so your remaining option is `long long int`, that can hold numbers between `-0x8000000000000000` and `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

You will need to do couple more adjustments: you need to explicitly specify that your constant is of type `long long` by using `LL` suffix, and you now need to shift by `64 - c`, not by `32 - c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fitsBits(long long x, int n) {
   long long r;
   int c;
   c = 65 + ~n;
   r = !(((x << c)>>c)^x);
   return r;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", fitsBits(0x80000000LL, 0x20));
    return 0;
}
```

Link to IDEONE: http://ideone.com/G8I3kZ

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way I could get this done without change the int bits?

Comment: WIthout that you cannot pass the value of `0x80000000` to your function. You have to use a bigger type.

Answer (score 1):

Left shifts that cause overflow are undefined for signed types. Hence the compiler may optimise `(x<<c)>>c` as simply `x`, and the entire function reduces down to `return 1;`.

Probably you want to use unsigned types.

A second cause of undefined behavior in your code is that `c` may be greater than or equal to the width of int. A shift of more than the width of the integer type is undefined behavior.

Comment: in this case actually an arithmetic shift is intended, and the function works correctly, so I don't know how the OP got that result

Comment: `c = 33 + ~n = 33 + (-n - 1) = 32 - n`, so as long as n is a valid shift (which is the case), c will never be larger than int's width

Answer (score -2):

```
r = (((x << c)>>c)^x); //This will give you 0, meaning r = 0;
```

OR

```
r = !((x << c)>>c);
```

Your function can be simplified to

```
int fitsBits(int x) {

    int r, c; 
    c = 33; 
    r = (((x << c)>>c)^x);

    return r;
}
```

Note that when NOT(`!`) is brought you're asking for opposite of `r`

Comment: No, your "simplified" version is completely incorrect. Shifting an amount larger than the width of the type `(x << 33) >> 33` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: On my system and his system (i think) int x gives 4233790, he did not initialize it to 0 or anything, even at that it still works

Comment: Is there a need of initialization here, when the values aren't used before assignment? The requirement is that it returns 1 if the number can be represented in n bits and 0 if not, and you return "4233790"? You remove the second parameter completely, making the function meaningless.

Comment: The second parameter int n, that happens to be ~n, does that not mean complement of variable n? what difference does it make with having it. You can bring it if you like,,, I only feel its waste of time

Comment: I don't take this silly argument with you when you don't even understand the function feature and requirement

Comment: No, am not arguing, its best you make me understand

Comment: I can't understand your English even after I tried my best. So it's easy to understand why you don't understand the requirements. Let me restate that: you are given 2 parameters: x and n, and you must find out if x can be represented in n bits. Now you dropped n, who allows you to do that and how can the others call your function? And who allows you to change the meaning of that parameter from n to ~n? In your function you can do anything but the inputs will conform to the specs. If you change that, others can't call the function too.

Comment: run the test code `for (long long i = 0; i < 0xFFFFFFFF; i++) if (fitsBits(i, 32) != yourFitsBits(i)) printf("ERROR\n");` and see how many correct cases your code get. And it's for only 1 value of n. Try any `fitsBits(i, n)` with n < 32 and there's no way to call your function

Comment: Thanks, I love that explanation